# Getting a Flask FileStorage object into LangChain TextLoader() .load() function?

Tags: python, flask, langchain

I need to use the TextLoader().load() in Langchain which takes a filepath (string) or blob as the input. Right now, I have my files in a FileStorage object in Flask. Is there a way I can somehow get this object to work in the TextLoader().load(). Thank you!

I tried to put the FileStorageObject.read() into the TextLoader() but then there was an error when I tried the .load()

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to save the file permanently, you can write its contents to a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile), which will be automatically deleted after closing. You can then pass the generated file name to the [`TextLoader`](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/document_loaders/langchain.document_loaders.text.TextLoader.html).

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template, 
    request
)
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files.get('file')
        if file and file.filename != '': 
            with NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
                file.save(temp)
                temp.seek(0)
                loader = TextLoader(temp.name)
                doc = loader.load()
                print(doc)
                
                # ...

    return render_template('index.html')
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise save the file and pass the path to the location used.